# SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I am creating laravel's registration part. My table name is '`owner`' and in code I wrote '`owner`' as a table name, but still when I  try to submit the registration form I am getting the error page as,

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'engage.owners' doesn't exist (SQL: insert into owners.....
```

As there is no `owners` table in my `engage` database, I don't know why it's trying to insert into `owners` table rather than `owner` table.

Comment: maybe it is becouse the laravel translate the tables name to plural ?

Comment: then what is the solution for this? Should I rename the table name to the 'owners'?

Comment: Could you provide us your model? if you are using eloquent else please provide you laravel db query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accourding to the docs: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent

you can change it like this:

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

```
class Flight extends Model
{
    /**
     * The table associated with the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'my_flights';
}
```

Keep in mind i never worked with laravel.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem during application deployment to hosting, although everything worked fine on my local server. It turned out that I had a `SELECT` from the database in the code that was taking data from the `ARTISTS` table. And in my database, my table was written as `artists` (in small letters). Perhaps this is a MySQL problem (in my case), since I have version 8 installed locally, and on the hosting it is 5.6.

There is also a strict mode in MySQL that you can turn off to avoid this problem.